# Fetch values from 3 tables without redundancy-SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, select

I want to retrieve column values of Name from 3 different tables

```
  Table1 contains Name
  Table2 contains Name, BAmt
  Table3 contains Name, RAmt
```

Now I want to fetch names from all the 3 tables.
Let's say the table contains these values

```
   Table1:     Table2:                    Table3:
   Name        Name        BAmt           Name         RAmt
1. Jack      1.Alice       1000         1.Mark         5000
2. Mark      2.Jack        500          2.Tarzon       1000
3. Ricky                                3.Beth         5500
                                        4.Jack         100
```

Now I want a table that contains all the names (without any repeats of any name). New table should ideally contain these values

```
  Name    BAmt      RAmt
1.Jack    500       100
2.Mark              5000
3.Ricky
4.Alice   1000    
5.Tarzon            1000
6.Beth              5500
```

Here it has ignored repeats but has taken the necessary values of those columns from the table.
What kind of a select statement should I use.
Here is something I think, but I guess its wrong approach:

```
    Statement statement1 = db.createStatement("SELECT DISTINCT Name,BAmt,RAmt FROM Table1,Table2,Table3");
                    statement1.prepare();
                    statement1.execute();
```

Please guide.

Comment: you have to do a natual join or give the join a on parameter? I dont get what you want to try because the join will do excact what you have  shown in the example (even without the distinct)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to [union all](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) all your tables to get that outline:

```
select Name, 
       ifnull (sum(BAmt), 0) BAmt,
       ifnull (sum(RAmt), 0) RAmt
from
(
  select Name, 
         null BAmt,
         null RAmt
    from Table1
   union all
  select Name,
         BAmt,
         null
    from Table2
   union all
  select Name,
         null,
         RAmt
    from Table3
) allTables
group by Name
order by Name
```

EDIT: updated to replace nulls with zeros.
See [Documentation for ifnull](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#ifnull).

Comment: I would just like to know how can I add a ' 0 ' to the places where there is a null.I would like to do it without an update table statement.Would substituting a ' 0 ' in the places of null in the above code work(I doubt).

Comment: @techie Please check my revised answer.

Comment: Hats off ! It never clicked to me to use ifnull in this way.Thanks again.:)

Answer (score 0):

The Join will take care of it:

```
select name, bamt, ramt from table1 t1 left outer join table2 t2 on t1.name = t2.name left outer join table3 on t1.name = t3.name order by name;
```